# Highcharts refresh tooltip on button click not working with boost modul

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-boost

I use Highcharts to draw my charts with the boost modul. I have multiple data series, with a shared tooltip.The X-axis values are the same for all data series. When I now click on a button, I want to show the shared tooltip. My input is the index of the x-axis point. Here my code, for simplification I use two small data arrays and I want to show the tooltip on index=2:

```
var chart=$('#container').highcharts({
    boost: {
             useGPUTranslations: true,
             seriesThreshold: 1,
           },
    series: [{
        name: 'Data1',
        data: [24.2, 24.6, 26.7, 28.6, 30.1, 29.0, 27.5, 27.2, 27.4, 28.2, 27.4, 25.6]
    }, {
        name: 'Data2',
        data: [14.1, 16.9, 22.4, 28.6, 32.8, 33.8, 31.0, 29.8, 29.2, 26.0, 20.3, 15.4]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: [true],
        shared: true,
    }
}).highcharts();

$('#showTooltipID').on('click', function() {
chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[2], chart.series[1].points[2]]);
  });
```

Example with `seriesThreshold: 1,` http://jsfiddle.net/hu5qatjn/34/ -> not working!

Example with `seriesThreshold: 3,` http://jsfiddle.net/hu5qatjn/35/ -> working!(boost modul not active)

So what am I doing wrong with the boost modul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using the boost module the point is not rendered on the initial load to save some performance, that's why your current approach doesn't work - the point object doesn't have enough data/properties to trigger the tooltip. We need to render the point programmatically before will be passed to the `tooltip.refresh` function.

```
$('#showTooltipID').on('click', function() {
    const series1 = chart.series[0],
                series2 = chart.series[1],
                point1 = series1.getPoint(series1.points[2]),
                point2 = series2.getPoint(series2.points[2]);
                

  chart.tooltip.refresh([point1, point2]);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8gos3cx2/

Comment: Thanks, I think that goes in the right direction, but is not 100% the thing I'm looking for. Here an updated example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/4gnh5rmk/13/
We have two arrays with 10000 elements each. I want to show the tooltip on index 50, but the tooltip is displayed on index 661 (=x value).

Comment: @xFL, notice that not all points are rendered - it is related to the boost limitation. Check your `series.points.length` in the console - the amount of the rendered points depends on the chart.width. As you can find `It bypasses some of the standard Highcahrts features, applies some trade-offs and focuses on handling and rendering as many data points as possible as quickly as possible` https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

Comment: so the only possible solution with the boost modul is to calculate the closest index which is shown in the chart? Kind of this way: http://jsfiddle.net/uv8ypx6d/6/ Or is there another nicer way I'm missing?

Comment: Another idea that came to my mind is to render this particular points as an outstanding dummy series - that solution makes you sure that those points exist after each render: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/anw76js1/

Comment: Thanks for this additional idea. But in my final szenario I won't show the tooltip only once on button click. I will hover over a gpx track on a map and then will highlight the according tooltip. So I think always showing a dummy point in the chart is less performant then just searching for the nearest point already drawn in the chart.

Comment: @xFL I see, thanks for the info. But do you need to show this particular data or the nearest point is fine?

Comment: Of course the actual point would be nice, but I don't want to decrease the performance. So for the moment it is fine for me to show the nearest point.Or do you think it is possible to do it in a performant way? Thanks a lot for your answers :)

Comment: @xFL, all my ideas require to add these points and do and update on the chart which definitely will have a bad impact on the performance, so such big amount of data finding the nearest point will be the best solution.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your advice Sebastian! I will mark this as answer, because now I have the solution with finding the nearest point.